# Is there any python function that works exactly in same way of MATLAB image to colum "im2co" in-built function?

Tags: python, image-processing, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Can we convert the following MATLAB functions to corresponding python version:

```
x1 = im2col(original_image, [block_size block_size], 'distinct');
r1 = col2im(x1, [block_size block_size],[Hight Width], 'distinct');
```

I tried to write the following  two functions, but my output is not the same as MATLAB functions. It can not recover the same image back again. Please check my code below.

```
def im2col(mtx, block_size):
    mtx_shape = mtx.shape
    m=mtx.shape[0]
    n=mtx.shape[1]

    mblocks = np.ceil(m/block_size)
    nblocks = np.ceil(n/block_size)

    sx= int(mblocks)
    sy =int(nblocks)

    result = np.empty((block_size * block_size, sx * sy))
    # Moved along the line, so the first holding column (i) does not move down along the row (j)
    for i in range(sy):
        for j in range(sx):
            result[:, i * sx + j] = mtx[j:j + block_size, i:i + block_size].ravel(order='F')
    return result


def col2im(mtx, block_size, image_size):
    p = block_size[0]
    q = block_size[1]

    mblocks = np.ceil(image_size[0]/p)
    nblocks = np.ceil(image_size[1]/q)

    sx= int(mblocks)
    sy= int(nblocks)

    result = np.zeros(image_size)
    weight = np.zeros(image_size)  # Weight record of each cell numbers plus the repeated many times
    col = 0
    # Moved along the line, so the first holding column (i) does not move down along the row (j)
    for i in range(sy):
        for j in range(sx):
            #result[j:j + p, i:i + q] += mtx[:, col].reshape(block_size, order='F')
            result[j:j + p, i:i + q] = result[j:j + p, i:i + q]+ mtx[:, col].reshape(block_size)
            weight[j:j + p, i:i + q] = weight[j:j + p, i:i + q]+  np.ones(block_size)
            col = col + 1
    #return np.divide(result, weight), result
    #return result
    return np.divide(result, weight, out=np.zeros_like(result), where=weight!=0)
```

To run them:

```
image = cv2.imread('my_image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
hh = image.shape[0]
wh = image.shape[1]
blk_size =32
x1 = im2col(image, blk_size)  
res1 = col2im(x1, (blk_size, blk_size), (hh, wh))
```

I will be thankful if anyone provides an exact python version of MATLAB im2col with 'distinct' criteria.

However, online available functions provided [here(link)](https://www.programmersought.com/article/41521899259/)  can return the same image, but it also fail to provide the extact im2col output matrix as MATLAB im2col. There dimension is different. MATLAB gives x1 dimension as 1024x64, while python gives dimension of 1024x50625 which is not wanted.

Comment: The default `im2col` should work this way too based on [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html). Did you mean to specify `"distinct"` mode? it is not supported by the function you linked...

Comment: Have you tried re-writing the function yourself? where did you get stuck? The short answer is: no this does not already exist, and it will have to be written by somebody. Probably you.

Comment: Yes, "I want the distinct mode in python". And it is not working while using the function I provided.

Comment: Yes, I am also re-writing the function in python, although I could run it without error, but it is not giving the result that I got from MATLAB.

Comment: def im2col(mtx, block_size):
    mtx_shape = mtx.shape

    m=mtx.shape[0]
    n=mtx.shape[1]

    mblocks = m/block_size
    nblocks = np.ceil(n/block_size)


    sx= int(mblocks)
    sy =int(nblocks)
    
    result = np.empty((block_size * block_size, sx * sy))
    
    for i in range(sy):
        for j in range(sx):
            result[:, i * sx + j] = mtx[j:j + block_size, i:i + block_size].ravel(order='F')
    return result
    ## THIS is the function for im2col

Comment: def col2im(mtx, image_size, block_size):
    p = block_size[0]
    q = block_size[1]
    mblocks = np.ceil(image_size[0]/p)
    nblocks = np.ceil(image_size[1]/q)
    sx= int(mblocks)
    sy= int(nblocks)
    result = np.zeros(image_size)
    weight = np.zeros(image_size) 
    col = 0
    for i in range(sy):
        for j in range(sx):
            result[j:j + p, i:i + q] += mtx[:, col].reshape(block_size, order='F')
            weight[j:j + p, i:i + q] += np.ones(block_size)
            col += 1
    return result / weight

Comment: please edit your question with your code rather than pasting it in the comments. That way you can format it correctly for others to read.

Comment: Okay. I have edited the same with better details. Please help with a solution.

Comment: I have successfully achieved the desired result by writing my own function. Please visit here for my python codes.  https://github.com/Mullahz/Python-programs-for-MATLAB-in-built-functions